# Inherited member not found

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have a base class called KeyRatioSymbol.
I have a class inheriting from KeyRatioSymbol called GuruFocusKeyRatioSymbol.

KeyRatioSymbol has this update method:

```
        /// <summary>
    /// Updates an existing key ratio symbol by setting the values from the new <see cref="KeyRatioSymbol"/>.
    /// </summary>
    public virtual void Update<T>(T newKeyRatioSymbol) where T : KeyRatioSymbol
    {
        this.Identifier = newKeyRatioSymbol.Identifier;
    }
```

GuruFocusKeyRatioSymbol defines member CurrencyId and wants to override the update method to include the new CurrencyId when updating:

```
        private int _CurrencyId;
    /// <summary>
    ///  Gets or sets the CurrencyId
    /// </summary>
    public int CurrencyId { get { return this._CurrencyId; } set { this.SetProperty(ref this._CurrencyId, value); } }


    public override void Update<GuruFocusKeyRatioSymbol>(GuruFocusKeyRatioSymbol newKeyRatioSymbol)
    {
        base.Update(newKeyRatioSymbol);
        this.CurrencyId = x.CurrencyId; // Compiler error
    }
```

Now the compiler complains: 'GuruFocusKeyRatioSymbol' does not contain a definition for 'CurrencyId'...

Why does the compiler not find the CurrencyId memeber in the class GuruFocusKeyRatioSymbol?

Regards!

Comment: @AluanHaddad - sure it is; the base class defines the generic type argument of `T` while the derived class provides the type argument as `GuruFocusKeyRatioSymbol`.

Comment: From `this.CurrencyId = x.CurrencyId`, where is `x` defined?

Comment: Would be great if we could see a more complete example here.  For all we know you made a typo on a class name somewhere and the type for `this` or `x` isn't what you think it is.

Comment: @MetroSmurf Right but it is not doing what it looks like it is doing. The name of the type parameter `GuruFocusKeyRatioSymbol` is shadowing the name of the enclosing class `GuruFocusKeyRatioSymbol` which is overriding the method. That is why it is not working. `GuruFocusKeyRatioSymbol` is just another name of the base method's `T`. What I mean was you cannot specialize a type argument in an override. The intent is wrong but the syntax is indeed valid.

Comment: @AluanHaddad - you deleted your original comment and the intent of this discussion has been lost. Not much reason to continue.

Comment: @AluanHaddad: Thank you, too. You said the same as Servy which helped me unterstand the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `Update` method you simply named the generic argument `GuruFocusKeyRatioSymbol`, whereas you used the name `T` in the parent.  Naming the generic argument `GuruFocusKeyRatioSymbol` doesn't mean it's going to be of your `GuruFocusKeyRatioSymbol` type, you just now have two different types with that same name.  If you name the generic method argument `T`, which is the common convention, it will have the same behavior, but it will become apparent why objects of that type don't necessarily have a `CurrencyID`; they could be any type of key ratio symbol, not just that specific one.

Comment: Ah, thank you. By overriding the method I simply re-implemented it and renamed generic argument T (base class) into GuruFocusKeyRatioSymbol.